# Cannot forward the connection after reading connection size buffer

Tags: go, tcp, portforwarding

So I have port forwarding application using golang.
The system is simple , create listener on specific port then forward it into different IP with a same port

here is the code

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tcpAddr, err: = net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "127.0.0.1:2222")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    //Create the TCP listener
    tcpListener, err: = net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    conn, err: = tcpListener.Accept()

    for {
        go func() {
            buffer: = make([] byte, 1024)
            n,
            _: = bufio.NewReader(conn).Read(buffer)

            // Print buffer size
                fmt.Println(len(buffer[: n]));

            handleConnection(conn, "192.168.1.107", "2222")
        }()
    }
}

func forward(src, dest net.Conn) {
    io.Copy(src, dest)

    defer src.Close()
    defer dest.Close()
}

func handleConnection(c net.Conn, ip string, port string) {
    dialCheck: = net.Dialer {
        Timeout: time.Duration(5 * time.Second)
    }
    remote,
    err: = dialCheck.Dial("tcp", ip)

    if err != nil {
        defer c.Close()
    } else {
        go forward(c, remote)
        go forward(remote, c)
    }
}
```

But everytime the client wants to connect, the connection always timeout. Seems the bufreader not stopped after reading.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your actual code.  The code in the question does not compile.   Also, the call `bufio.NewReader(conn).Read(buffer)` will read up to 4096 bytes from the connection.   Any bytes read past the 1024 bytes read by the application are discarded.

Comment: The `bufio.Reader` may have buffered data, and buffering data is the purpose of using a `bufio.Reader`. If you want to only read a specific number of bytes, why are you using `bufio.NewReader`?

Comment: @CeriseLimón okay I have edited the code, and yes since I don't need much bytes (over 1024) it's not a problem.

Comment: @JimB sorry i'm still new on golang , but I have used Reader also same, seems like the connection already timed out before handleConnection function called

Comment: What do you mean by you "have used Reader also same"? You cannot create a `bufio.Reader` then immediately discard it. Please show a [mre] without using `bufio.Reader`.

Comment: `tcpListener.Accept()` will wait for a connection. once received, it dispatches an infinite number of goroutines. this is not right. you want `Accept()` inside of the `for` loop. what do you want achieve with `go forward(c, remote)` and `go forward(remote, c)` ?